# How can I install emacs customizations without apt-get?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm an emacs newbie trying to make the switch; after configuring org-mode to my liking (my primary reason for switching) the next thing I wanted to do was customize the colors.  *I know several people have asked about getting emacs color-theme to work, but I've been searching for over an hour and so far the instructions haven't helped me so please bear with me.*

I'm using GNU Emacs for OSX from [here](http://emacsformacosx.com/) on 10.6.7.

Most instructions on the web say to start by running

```
sudo apt-get install emacs-goodies-el
```

If I were running linux that'd be no problem, but Macs don't have `apt-get` that I know of so I'm trying to figure out what to do instead.

I found a copy of `color-theme.el` and the `themes/` folder in a tarball [here](http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/color-theme/) and put it in my `emacs.d/` directory.  Then I added the boilerplate stuff to my `init.el` file:

```
(setq load-path (append load-path (list "~/.emacs.d/themes")))
(setq load-path (append load-path (list "~/.emacs.d/color-theme.el")))

(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-robin-hood)
```

But when I load emacs I am still getting this error:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, color-theme
```

## My questions

- **Are there other things besides `color-theme` contained in `emacs-goodies-el` that are needed for color-theme to work properly on Mac?**
- **If so, where can I download these files and install them without `apt-get`?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

color-theme.el is not being developed so you may want avoid that.

Instead I suggest you to download Emacs 24.0.XX pretest version from that website. So you can simply call `M-x customize-themes` to change new inbuilt themes.

More over emacs 24 has its own package manager so you dont need to apt-get to install emacs packages. once you install Emacs 24, call `M-x list-packages` to see the available packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the structure of emacs-goodies, but if you look up the document of `load-path`, you'll find that it's a list of *directories*, not files.  So I'm not sure if your second `setq` is helpful.  Try removing it.

And in general, if you want to install some Emacs extension, just download it and put it somewhere.  Then add that directory to your `load-path`.  Depending on the extension, you may need to `require` it or write some `autoload`s.  I believe Emacs 24 has package support built in, but I haven't tried it yet.

And finally as others have mentioned, Emacs 24 has built-in theme support.  It's better to use that instead of `color-theme`, if you are using v24 (who's not, right? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you.  I would avoid using 24 until it's stable.  Instead, as [Darksair](https://superuser.com/users/116249/darksair) stated, your load-path is supposed to point to a path (directory), not a file.

Follow these steps:

1. [Download the gz file](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/color-theme.el.gz) from the link you listed above
2. Move the file to your directory

   ```
   %> mv ~/Downloads/color-theme.el ~/.emacs.d/
   ```
3. Add the path and settings to your emacs resource/profile/settings file

   ```
   %> emacs ~/.emacs
   [type]    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
   [type]    (require `color-theme)
   [type]       (color-theme-initialize)
   [type]       (color-theme-robin-hood) 
   {save} Ctrl+x Ctrl+s
   ```

---

For a more complete install, download the tarball and copy over the following contents to your .emacs.d/

- color-theme.el
- color-theme-autoloads.el
- themes/